# entity framework on wp7

Tags: c#, entity-framework, windows-phone-7

I've found [some blogs](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/01/06/entity-framework-code-first-odata-amp-windows-phone-client.aspx) that look like they are using Entity Framework to persist data from the windows phone to remote servers via WCF (at least thats what it looks like scanning the info)... but can Entity framework be run directly on the phone?  For instance, say I want to use [Sqlite](http://wmpoweruser.com/sqlite-for-windows-phone-7-created/), or even Azure as my backend... can I do it all without hosting a server to do the work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Entity Framework is currently not available on the phone itself. However the OData client libraries are which will let you query backends such as Azure.

Comment: bummer... I was hoping to use some of the code-first persistence ignorant stuff on the phone.